# If a transistor only gives you a maximum current flow, what's the maximum voltage?

Tags: voltage, transistors, current

In some data sheets of NPN transistors it only says "maximum collector - emitter current." But my question at what voltage is this current value given, because 1 ampere at 1 volt is somehow less energy than 1 ampere at 100 volts.

Answer (score 1):

The maximum collector-emitter current is an optimistic upper bound; it's the most you can shove through the transistor, ever.

The datasheet also has a maximum collector-emitter voltage, and a (generally wildly optimistic) maximum power dissipation.

Because that power dissipation is usually wildly optimistic, and is often at least somewhat optimistic, it's up to you to take the specified *parts* of the thermal behavior (the maximum junction temperature, which is also somewhat optimistic, and the junction-to-case thermal resistance), combine that with whatever method you're using to get heat out of the transistor and your intended ambient temperature that you want the device to run, and then *you* need to figure out the power handling capabilities of whatever circuit you're building using that transistor.

Answer (score 0):

It usually doesn't take much collector-emitter voltage to reach the maximum current when the transistor is On. If you increase the voltage above this level, the transistor resistance will increase accordingly so that you constantly drop the same current. This is how a basic current mirror works. As long as your transistor is biased-On, the transistor's resistance will automatically adjust so that you'll never really increase past your max current level. If you do increase your voltage high enough, you'll let the magic smoke out. That level should be in the data sheet.

You're absolutely right though that if you're not consuming the voltage elsewhere in the circuit at that given maximum current, you're heading for magic smoke release.

Comment: The question is about bipolar junction transistors, not FETs.

Comment: @JRE you're right. Same idea applies though.